# Count the number of select boxes with a selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of selectboxes on a form all with the CSS class of "topic". I just want to count the number of boxes with a selected value of "Yes" or "No" and not value="". My code below counts every selectbox. How do I restrict this to just Yes or No?

```
//Counts all of them instead of just the Yes/Nos
    var countTopic = $('.topic option:selected').length;
    alert(countTopic); 
    
    <select id="ddlTopic_ACH" class="topic">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Use `.filter()` - something like `$(".topic option:selected").filter(() => this.value !== '').length;`

Comment: Or attribute selector, eg `$(".topic option[value='Yes']:selected")` for count of yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the empty selector for this. Well the reverse to be precise :)

```js
let selectedOptions = $('#ddlTopic_ACH option:not(:empty):selected')

console.log(selectedOptions.length) // 1 --> Yes
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlTopic_ACH" class="topic">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Yes" selected>Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Don't forget `:selected`

Comment: @freedomn-m Indeed! I missed this :)